# QGIS 3.16 MSSQL Server Primary Key Issue

Tags: qgis

I have a GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table with all the proper fields.

I've tested a spatial table with BIGINT as primary key. All works fine and I am able to see the features and the attribute table with all of the records showing.

When I add any additional number fields to this table such as INT, FLOAT etc. I can no longer see all the records in the attribute table, only 1 filtered record displays which brings me to the belief that QGIS is unable to pick up the Primary Key correctly.

Is this a bug with MSSQL connection inside QGIS 3.16?

Comment: Do you have a reason to use BIGINT? pro/cons https://superuser.com/questions/390293/is-there-some-issue-in-have-bigint-column-as-primary-key-on-mysql

Comment: Yes I do, and that wasn't the question asked. Bug?

Comment: Its a bug in your version of QGIS https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348799/276 new version have a fix.

Comment: Thanks for that. Any idea which version has a fix for this?

Comment: Hopefully this was fixed for MSSQL also and not only Postgresql